# c++ Error in Qt: has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++, qt

```
void FindWords::getTextFile() {
    QFile myFile(":/FindingWords2.txt");
    myFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QTextStream textStream(&myFile);
    QString line = textStream.readAll();
    myFile.close();

    ui->textEdit->setPlainText(line);
    QTextCursor textCursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
    textCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 1);
}
```

The `QTextStream textStream(&myFile)` keeps giving me the error and I can't fix it.

Answer (score 25):

You forgot to include `<QTextStream>` or `<QFile>`.

Answer (score 3):

I added

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDataStream>
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same with previous one. You should consider adding more info if you have.